# How to Add PHP-Code to an attribute using DOM on PHP?

Tags: php, dom, attributes

How can I do somethink like this with PHP DOM?

```
<img src="<?php echo $picsrc; ?>">
```

This Code

```
$node->setAttribute('src','<?php echo $picsrc;?>');
```

does escape the PHP Tag.

```
<img src="&lt;?php echo $picsrc; ?&gt;">
```

Is there a way to use

```
$dom->createProcessingInstruction()
```

for Attribute Values?

Comment: instead of `<?php echo ..?>` try `$picsrc` directly, `$node->setAttribute('src',$picsrc);`

Comment: So you are generating PHP files dynamically? Hmm. That's tricky. Maybe create a placeholder and replace it afterwards

Comment: @GeoPhoenix Doing $node->setAttribute('src',$picsrc); don't get the needed Result because I have to insert a <?php ?>. The cause is, I have to insert a mysql query an some other Stuff there.

Comment: @Pekka Creating a Placeholder would do this Job, but I can't believe there isn't a easier way to do this. For using a Placeholder, I have to build html-file with Placeholders, loading file to string an replace the placeholders with <?php ?>

Comment: Well, this is a *very* special case and you're essentially looking to create invalid HTML. Arguably, a HTML builder is rightly not going to help you do that

Answer (score 1):

You should try this

```
$srcPath = '<?php echo $picsrc;?>';
$node->setAttribute('src', html_entity_decode($srcPath));
```

Comment: By doing setAttribute() the String is still unmodified. The Modification happens by building the HTML file from DOM with $dom->save($filename); So I can't docode anything on this string.

Answer (score 0):

@thecatontheflat was right, decoding is the Answer!

But using it this way:

```
$node->setAttribute('src','<?php echo $picsrc; ?>');

$doc->save('dynamic.php');
$html = htmlspecialchars_decode(file_get_contents('dynamic.php'));
$html = html_entity_decode($html);
file_put_contents('dynamic.php',$html);
```

Don't try to avert the conversion, just revoke it. ;)

thanks at all.